# Node.js `request.get`: store body in variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, coffeescript

I’m new to Node.js, and so sorry for what is probably a dumb question…

Here’s my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env coffee --bare

#   3rd party
request  = require('request')
request.defaults({'encoding': 'utf8'})

module.exports.fetchDepartments = fetchDepartments

fetchDepartments = (url) ->
    _body = ''

    getHandler = (error, response, body) -> 
        util.debug "HTTP response code: #{response.statusCode}"

        if error
            util.error error
        else    
            _body = body

    request.get(url, getHandler)
    _body

console.log fetchDepartments('https://ntst.umd.edu/soc/')
```

The console is printing the call to `util.debug()`, but it seems that `_body` remains an empty  string.

…How can I store the HTML from the HTTP response?!?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: @SLaks I had a feeling it was something like that.  So, how do I accomplish my goal, instead?

Comment: You need to accept a callback or return a promise.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be returning the `_body` *before* the request is completed.

The request is not synchronous, so you'll almost certainly want to define a callback instead.  In plain JavaScript, that would be:

```
fetchDepartments('https://ntst.umd.edu/soc', function (err, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

What it's *currently* doing is:

1. Initialise `_body` to `''`
2. Create (but not execute!) `getHandler`
3. Start the request
4. Return the (still-empty) `_body`
5. Log the (empty) `_body`
6. *Later:* the request completes, calling `getHandler`
7. `getHandler()` updates `_body`

What you need to do is to make `fetchDepartments` accept callback function, so that whatever code processes `_body` can wait until the request is complete.

Comment: No--if (inside of `getHandler()`) I call `console.log(body)`, the HTML prints.  My issue is that I need to **store** it, rather than printing it and losing that data.

Comment: That's because `getHandler` executes asynchronously, after the request is completed.  However, where you *currently* have it, the return value is calculated instantly, just after the request was sent.  So it *is* updating `_body` - just after you've already  logged it.

Comment: I've extended my answer to include the steps it's *currently* taking, to try and help explain why it doesn't currently work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  I now get what was going wrong.  However, my goal is to be able to store `body`.  How would I do that?

Comment: You *are* already storing the result in `_body`.  The issue is that you are logging the value of `_body` before the request is completed.  If you want to do something with `_body`, then it has to only execute after the request completes.

Comment: Hey @cloudfeet , thanks again.  May sound weird, but I’ve never actually *written* callback functions before. Could you give a quick example?

Comment: @Zearin - I'm not a CoffeeScript person, but I've translated your code into JavaScript, and then modified it to use a callback. You can see both the translated and modified versions [in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7316880).